# add event to TableCalender flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, table-calendar

I am new in create calender in flutter.
I try to create table_calendar, and add event to the calender but I got an error.

The code I did:

```
Map<DateTime, List> _events = {};
DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
DateTime _selectedDate;
@override
void initState() {
_selectedDate = _focusedDay;
DateTime d = DateTime.utc(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day, 12);
_events[d] = [];
_events[d].add("Event A");
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
children: [
 TableCalendar(
  focusedDay: _focusedDay,
    onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
      if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedDate = selectedDay;
          _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        });
      }
    },
    eventLoader: (day) {
      return _events.keys.contains(day) ? _events[day] : [];
    },
  )
],
);
```

The error I got is:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Calender(dirty, state: _CalenderState#3429f):
The getter 'year' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your main problem is this line in your `initState()`:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.utc(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day, 12);
```

The eventLoader is passed `DateTime`s at midnight (at 00:00:00.000). When you add "Event A" to your event map, the key you give it is  a `DateTime` for today at noon since you give it an hour parameter of 12. In the event loader, you check if there's a value in your event map with a key of today at midnight. Since there isn't, it thinks there's no event today.

You're also missing the `firstDay` and `lastDay` parameter for your `TableCalendar`, which are both required.

It seems like the error you mentioned is coming from code outside of the snippet you posted. Your only use of the 'year' getter is `DateTime.now().year`, which is perfectly valid.

Below is an example of the calendar widget with those two fixes applied. I also added several other small improvements to your code with comments explaining those improvements. Here's a link to an image showing the resulting calendar, which properly shows the event you added to today's date:

[The resulting calendar running in an iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PulEF.png)

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Calendar> createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  final Map<DateTime, List> _events = {};

  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  // Instead of initializing in initState, just add the "late" modifier.
  late DateTime _selectedDate = _focusedDay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // This is where your problem is. The event loader is passed DateTimes with
    // the time component set to zero (midnight). d is set to noon. Just delete
    // the argument of "12" for hours.
    DateTime d = DateTime.utc(
      DateTime.now().year,
      DateTime.now().month,
      DateTime.now().day,
    );
    // Just add "Event A" to the list on this line
    _events[d] = ["Event A"];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TableCalendar(
          // Make sure you add the required arguments "firstDay" and "lastDay"
          firstDay: DateTime(1970),
          lastDay: DateTime.now(),
          focusedDay: _focusedDay,
          onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
            if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedDate = selectedDay;
                _focusedDay = focusedDay;
              });
            }
          },
          eventLoader: (day) {
            // Use a null aware operator "??" to make this line simpler. If
            // _events[day] is null, return the empty list instead.
            return _events[day] ?? [];
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```